# App.config file versioned with application?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, version, app-config

I have an application that gets compiled into an executable. It relies on an app.config file (which gets turned into a MyApp.exe.config file).

I needed to make an update to the application, so made the change, recompiled, and then replaced the application.exe file. But it wouldn't work...until I also copied up the new app.config file with it, even though the app.config hadn't changed.

Can someone explain this? Does the app.config become a dependency that is versioned like any other dll? I thought since it is a config file (essentially a text file), it wouldn't be versioned and depended on in this way.

Comment: You really need to describe what "it wouldn't work" means. Was there an exception? What actually went wrong?

Comment: The app.config file is just an xml configuration file. There's no versioning like with assemblies.

Is it possible some of the changes you made added some config to the app.config that's in the original app.config. For example, adding service references will change the app.config with endpoints and config needed for web services.

what error do you get?

Answer (score -1):

The app.config file is just an xml configuration file. There's no versioning like with assemblies.

Is it possible some of the changes you made added some config to the app.config that's in the original app.config.  For example, adding service references will change the app.config with endpoints and config needed for web services.

what error do you get?